# jQuery draggable, make faded copy on drag start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm building an application with jQuery UI and it's draggable and droppable plugins. My goal is to archieve the following:

[image]

Basically, I want when the drag start to leave a faded copy behind the item which is dragged. Note that the dragged item is image, and it's different everytime.
My code is close to the default draggable/droppable example in the jQuery documentation.

```
_this.draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        _this.addClass("closest");
        .....morecode....
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        _this.removeClass("closest");
        ...code..               
    }
});
```

My first idea was to `clone()` the item on drag start and place it on the dragged item default position with lower `z-index` and position absolute, but since my page is responsive it will break the whole UI. Placing the cloned item `after()` the original one isn't a solution because jQuery UI make his own placeholder when dragging, which I couldn't figure out how to disable.

Any suggestions for proper solutions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: "jQuery UI make his own placeholder when dragging, which I couldn't figure out how to disable" http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper

Comment: Would the built-in `draggable({ opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone" });` not work? it's what you are describing but in reverse, where the dragged item is faded but the original (starting version) is left normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `helper` and `stop` methods/properties with `toggleclass` to return the clone and set the original to a custom faded class, like:

```
  $("#draggable").draggable({
      helper: function (event) {
          var ret = $(this).clone();
          $(this).toggleClass("ghost");
          return ret;
      },
      stop: function (event, ui) {
          $(this).toggleClass("ghost");
      }
  });
```

CSS

```
.ghost {
     opacity: .5;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xms8W/2/

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer, because I actually needed to do some changes to the helper, so I need to use the helper function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have used the built-in opacity option, but you want the item that's in the starting position to be opaque instead

`<div class="selector">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>`

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(e){
        $(e.target).css({opacity: 0.5});
    },
    stop: function(e){ // need to put it back on stop
        $(e.target).css({opacity: 1});
    },
});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/EQpwb/2/

Though, operating systems work the same way as jqueryui with the item you're dragging being the opaque one. Personally I would stick with that.

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    opacity: 0.5,
});
```